# Socket emit fails

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

```
  socket.on('sign_in', function(idA, idB) {
var idA = idA; //global vars
var idB = idB; //ignore this var
if (!clients[idA]) {
  clients[idA] = socket.id;
}
console.log(idA + ' has connected');
io.to(clients[idA]).emit('sign_in', idA + ' has connected'); });

io.emit('sign_in', "user is signed in");
```

I am trying to emit the message,"'idA' has connected" to my android client. The problem is that the emitting to a specific client only works once. After it is called once the server stops sending the line "'idA' has connected". I have to reset my server in order to get it to work again, but the problem lingers. The basic io emit function consistently works which leads me to think its a problem with the specific client emit. 
I have tried adding the option 'forceNew' to my socket connection but it does not change anything (I am using nkzawa socket-client).

my client code:

```
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
        options.forceNew = true;
        socket = IO.socket(HOST, options);
```

and then using a new thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "attempting to connect socket");
            socket.connect();
            idA = "user1"
            idB = "nicknameOfUser1"
            socket.emit("sign_in", idA, idB);
        }
    }).start();
```

receiving the emit:

```
socket.on("sign_in", new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
                    String message = (String) args[0];
                    System.out.println(message);
            }
        });
```

Again, the message "'idA' has connected" will only print out the first time. But the message "user has signed in" is called consistently each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my emit was written incorrectly.

```
io.to(clients[idA]).emit('sign_in', idA + ' has connected');
```

should be

```
clients[idA].emit('sign_in', idA + ' has connected');
```

also be sure to assign

```
clients[idA] = socket;
```